# Strange issue in file that needs attention view in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold

I have a document library where many documents are missing a mandatory column value; due to this, I can see the "Files that need attention" view in my document library. The strange part is that this view doesn't display any data; it just keeps asking "**Load more items**" but never loads any data. I know there are many documents that need mandatory metadata to be updated. How can we load this view for the data fixing?

[image: Load more items]

Comment: Is it the default view called All Items that your screenshot shows? How many items in your library? Are there special columns or customize parts in the library?

Comment: This is out of the box "Files that need attention" view - we don't have control on this, this view only visible in list modern experience.

Comment: I am testing in my environment, when I set the "Files that need attention" view to the default view, and then refresh, this view will be displayed as empty (the prompt is This folder is empty and yours is not the same). But when I refresh again, and re-enter, it is working fine.   
So, can you tell me what custom operations you have done for this library?
Perhaps, you can try to use the browser's privacy mode or switch browsers to try.

Comment: Hi Amy - I haven't done any customization for this document library, but it has more than 5K documents without filling up the mandatory columns. I tried switching the browser even using private mode, it didn't work.

Comment: What you meant by "Refresh again, and re-enter, it is working fine?" - Could you please explain on this process.